# How to slice the row index in dataframe?

Tags: python

I would like to remove some characters/values in the row index for the following dataframe:

```
    Date             Adj Close
2020-01-02 00:00:00 96.84999847
2020-01-03 00:00:00 96.83999634
2020-01-06 00:00:00 96.66999817
2020-01-07 00:00:00 96.98000336
2020-01-08 00:00:00 97.33000183
2020-01-09 00:00:00 97.44999695
2020-01-10 00:00:00 97.36000061
```

And my desired output:

```
    Date     Adj Close
2020-01-02  96.84999847
2020-01-03  96.83999634
2020-01-06  96.66999817
2020-01-07  96.98000336
2020-01-08  97.33000183
2020-01-09  97.44999695
2020-01-10  97.36000061
```

How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=False), Just set UTC to false and that will strip the offset from the date column

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing a datetime object in that column, then you will have to truncate the time aspect from it like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
```

If you are simply storing a text containing date & time, you can just slice the text like this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'][:10]
```

Comment: I got the approach, but the data is being row index now.
How could I amend it?

Comment: Add a loop for each row in your data-frame and then you can separate the time.